# Sum with expression and group by in Access 2007 / VBA

Tags: sql, group-by, ms-access-2007, sum

Here's the code I'm starting with, that doesn't work quite right:

```
 UPDATE mt
 SET mt.action = 'A', mt.TQA = TRUE,
     mt.OPID = 'SYS', mt.rc= 'DAR', mt.h='DAR'
 WHERE EXISTS 
 (
     SELECT mt.Account FROM mt AS pm
     WHERE mt.Account = pm.Account
     GROUP BY pm.Account, pm.[amount] + Nz(pm.[SFS],0)
     HAVING (pm.[amount] + Nz(pm.[SFS],0) > 500)
 );
```

what I need is a total sum of amount and SFS for all instances of the account, where that's more than 500.

For example, if I have the following table

```
 Account   Amount   SFS
 123       350.00   0.00
 123       125.00   125.00
 123       350.00   0.00
 123       125.00   125.00
 234       1600.00  5.00
 345       2.50     4.60
```

I should get

```
 123    1200.00
 234    1605.00
```

What I get with the code above is the different totals alone, not groups, which means they're not caught by the >500:

```
 123    350.00
 123    250.00
 234    1605.00
```

Can anyone help? This has 5 of us stumped.

Comment: Fair enough. When I put in the tag, I was thinking "this will be used via vba", but it's not actually in the question, so you're correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use two subqueries. Here's the final that worked.

```
UPDATE mt
SET rc='DAR'
WHERE  Account IN
(
  SELECT mt.account
  FROM 
    (
    SELECT mt.Account, SUM(mt.[amount]+Nz(mt.[SFS],0)) as total
    FROM mt
    GROUP BY mt.Account
    )    
  WHERE total>=500
);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `pm.[amount] + Nz(pm.[SFS],0)` from your group by clause - you don't want to group by the sum, only the accounts

Comment: I agree, but when I do that with the subquery (assuming the update is fine), Access gives me the following error: You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression '(pm.amount+nz(pm.sfs,0)>500' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: This is relevant: All fields in the SELECT field list must either be included in the GROUP BY clause or be included as arguments to an SQL aggregate function.

trying something new...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
UPDATE mt
SET mt.action = 'A', mt.TQA = TRUE,
    mt.OPID = 'SYS', mt.rc= 'DAR', mt.h='DAR'
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT mt.Account FROM mt AS pm
    WHERE mt.Account = pm.Account
    GROUP BY pm.Account, pm.[amount] + Nz(pm.[SFS],0)
    HAVING (SUM(pm.[amount] + Nz(pm.[SFS],0)) > 500)
);
```

Comment: Nope - same problem as what what Sean recommended, as best as I can tell. I did find a solution though! About to post it.